# Stalling an animation

Tags: android

I have created a splash screen in my app which loads an animation over a 4 second period & then loads the main screen directly. But I want the image to stall for a second before moving onto the main screen. Im aware that Android has no pause() method in this context so how would I do this?

Should I create a new thread, use te timer class or what? Im just looking for best programming practice for this.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest thing would be to simply add an additional animation to your animation set that  doesn't change any settings but has a duration of 1 second. (ie, translateanimation from 0,0 to 0,0).

Comment: So make an animation set with the original animation and this animation that is a total of 5 seconds, and set the offset for this new animation to 4 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

How does your splash screen work now? Is it in it's own thread while it loads the app? If so just Thread.sleep(1000) after it's done loading.

Comment: No - I have created the animation in a separate xml file and load it using the java class I apply it to. I use the AnimationUtils class to do it not a thread, because every-time I try to use the Thread option it crashes the app!

Comment: Then shoot for slund's answer. It seems like that would be your fix.

Comment: Hi - So I decided to implement the TimerTask class in order to schedule my programs, which did work. I called the Timer instance in the method onAnimationEnd() which starts the timer :P

Comment: Cool. I would write an answer to this question and accept it, so that everyone else knows you solved it.